# I wrote a code of a booking system and want to fill my array in res objects (I created a class called Res), What is wrong with my array fill ,,,,,,,,,

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner nameInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name; 
    System.out.print("What is your Last name? ");
    name = nameInput.nextLine();

    int maxSeats = 200; 
    
    Res seatChart[] = new Res[maxSeats];
    Arrays.fill(objectArray,new Res());     \

    Res res1 = new Res(name);
    System.out.println(res1.getName());
    System.out.println(res1.getisFilled());
    System.out.println(res1.getnamelength());
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain in your question what you want to do with this line `Arrays.fill(objectArray,new Res())` ?

Comment: That fills every element of the array with a reference to a _single_ instance of `Res`.  If you want 200 different `Res` instances you'll need to use a loop.

Comment: ok thx can u pls send umm a code that does it